# Resume writing guideline for applying a PhD position

Tags: phd, computer-science, cv, europe

I've been working a Software Engineer for almost 7 years. A few months ago I finalized my Master's degree on Computer Science, and now I'm thinking in applying to a Phd program in a European College.

I have no prior experience in research -besides the Dissertation for the Msc- so now my resume is very enterprise oriented. I'm a big fan of [Gayle Laakmann resume tips](http://www.careercup.com/resume), so the current version of my resume is very goal-oriented and brief but I'm not sure if that's what academia expects of a resume.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do a resume to applying to a Phd Position in Computer Science? Also, a template or an example would be of great help.

Comment: Re: examples, many of us have our CVs available on our websites (for example, my own); of course, depending on where we are in our careers they are more or less related to the kind (in terms of length/breadth) of CV a PhD applicant might have.

Comment: It's crucial to know which countries, in particular, zou are applying to, since conventions vary very much across Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of a University admitting students based on a resume.  Universities use transcripts, standardized test, statements of purpose, and letters of recommendation to admit students.

The statement of purpose is probably the closest to a resume, but this is meant to be more of a narrative of why you're pursuing a PhD, not a sales pitch about how awesome you are (which is what a resume is).

From your question it sounds like you may not have much experience with graduate research.  This is fine, but it sounds like you're approaching the PhD as another job, which is wrongheaded.  A PhD gets you out of the trenches of customer demands and allows you to focus on "pie in the sky" problems.  If you want to remain business focused, a PhD may not be for you.

If you do want a PhD, you should speak with your profs. from your MS degree.  They will be able to guide you towards universities and programs that will appreciate your industry experience.  Is there a reason you don't want to apply in the US (using the word resume suggest you're American).